# AddClass and RemoveClass revert back to original

Tags: jquery

I have been working on this and been googling around for solution.

**Background**
I want to remove the class "customBox disabled" and add the class "customBox". I have tried several ways; .removeClass("customBox disabled").addClass("customBox"), toggle(....,....) and also the below but to no avail. The problem is the code did changed to the new class but it got revert back as soon as the program end. But why? Any expert?

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnStep2", function() {

    alert($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).attr("class"));
    if ($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().children().is(':disabled')) {
        alert("disabled");
        if ($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).hasClass("customBox disabled")) {
            $("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).removeClass();
            alert($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).attr("class"));
            $("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).addClass("customBox disabled");
            alert($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).attr("class"));
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("enabled");
        if ($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).hasClass("customBox")) {
            $("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).removeClass();
            alert($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).attr("class"));
            $("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).addClass("customBox");
            alert($("#step2").children().children().children().children().eq(1).children().eq(1).attr("class"));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: For the love of god use a variable

Comment: `"customBox disabled"` is not one class, it‘s two classes – the class `customBox`, and the class `disabled`. And if you just want to switch the `disabled` one on and off, then use `toggleClass`.

Comment: try to use `$.find()` instead of multiple `$.children()` so that code will be more cleaner and readable.

Comment: in you code `remove class()` is blank. And also you chain the methods. No need to call no of time to the same object for `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Comment: There is two changes in your one use .find() instead of .children() and .removeClass() method is blank specify which class you want to remove.

Comment: please post your html too

Comment: Thanks all However it went back straight after it change. Why?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to replace all those .children methods. Just use find() method to make the code cleaner and easier to read.

Second I want to clear to you that "disabled" and "customBox" are two separate classes. By looking at description of your question, You want to toggle only "disabled" class. "customBox" class does not have to do anything.

After all this try code below. Hope that helps

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnStep2", function() {
    var custom_box = $("#step2").find(".customBox");
    if (custom_box.length > 0){
        custom_box.toggleClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi i did as what you described. It gave me the same error. The class did changed to only customBox when the condition is enabled, however it reverted back to customBox disabled again.

Comment: Explain what are you actually trying to acieve in simple words. The code i wrote, adds "disabled" class to customBox if its not present and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, there are two conditions. One is to check if the other div is enabled. If yes, it will trigger the next check. However i cannot use what you suggested, because there are more than three customBox of the same class name. Anyway, i solved it. Thanks a lot. I will enjoy coding. Lots to code.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved when i pasted the following code on top. Thanks everyone for your help. Truly appreciate it.

```
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
```